# Solution for continued fraction

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, continued-fractions

To solve the finite continued fraction $[2,....,2]$, can I use this solution.

Let $y$ be the value of $[2,....,2]$.
Then $y=[2;y]=2+\frac{1}{y}$.

So $y-2=\frac{1}{y}$.
Thus $y^2-2y-1=0$

My question is is my method correct. Is this approach suitable to solve $[2,....,2]$

Comment: Please stop posting and deleting similar questions. I will be flagging similar posts I see in the future as spam.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is only valid for the *infinite* continued fraction.

If the continued fraction has a finite length (say, length $5$), then

$$y = 2 + \frac1{2 + \frac1{2 + \frac1{2 + \frac12}}} \ne 2 + \frac1y = 2 + \frac1{2 + \frac1{2 + \frac1{2 + \frac1{2 + \frac12}}}}.$$

The same thing happens for any length.

Instead, you can just compute the fraction for $y$ recursively: You have $[2] = 2$, $[2;2] = 2+\frac12 = \frac32$, $[2;2,2] = 2 + \frac1{3/2} = \frac53$, and in general, if you got $y_n$ for $n$ $2$'s, then you get $y_{n+1} = 2 + \frac1{y_n}$.

Comment: @SenJee The answer depends on how many steps there are in the continued fraction. To simplify it, you have to compute the recurrence.

Comment: @SenJee I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this approach suitable to solve $[2,....,2]$

No, because your continued fraction is finite. Moreover, it is rational and the solutions of $y^2-2y-1=0$ are irrational.

*Notation*. 
\begin{equation*}
x_{n}=a_0+\cfrac{1}{a_1+\cfrac{1}{\begin{array}{ccc}a_{2}+ & & \\& \ddots & \\& & +\cfrac{1}{a_{n-1}+\cfrac{1}{a_{n}}}\end{array}}}=
\left[ a_{0};a_{1},a_{2},\ldots ,a_{n}\right] =[2;\underset{n\text{
elements}}{\underbrace{2,\ldots ,2}}]=\frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}}.
\end{equation*}
We then have $x_{0}=[a_{0}]=\frac{p_{0}}{q_{0}}=\frac{a_{0}}{1}=\frac{2}{1}$
 with $(p_{0},q_{0})=(2,1)$; and $x_{1}=\left[ a_{0};a_{1}\right] =\frac{p_{1}}{q_{1}
}=a_{0}+\frac{1}{a_{1}}=\frac{a_{0}a_{1}+1}{a_{1}}=\frac{5}{2}$; with $
(p_{1},q_{1})=(5,2)$.

For $n\geq 2$ the integers $p_{n},q_{n}$ satisfy the
*fundamental recurrent relation*
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_{n} &=&a_{n}p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}=2p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}, \\
q_{n} &=&a_{n}q_{n-1}+q_{n-2}=2q_{n-1}+q_{n-2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The next two terms of the finite sequence $(x_n)$ are
\begin{eqnarray*}
x_{2} &=&\left[ a_{0};a_{1},a_{2}\right] =a_{0}+\frac{1}{a_{1}+1/a_{2}}=
\frac{p_{2}}{q_{2}}=\frac{2p_{1}+p_{0}}{2q_{1}+q_{0}}=\frac{2(5)+2}{2(2)+1}=
\frac{12}{5}, \\
x_{3} &=&\left[ a_{0};a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}\right] =a_{0}+\frac{1}{
a_{1}+1/(a_{2}+1/a_{3})}=\frac{p_{3}}{q_{3}}=\frac{2p_{2}+p_{1}}{2q_{2}+q_{1}
}=\frac{2(12)+5}{2(5)+2}=\frac{29}{12}, \\
&&\cdots 
\end{eqnarray*}

and
\begin{equation*}
(p_{2},q_{2})=(12,5),(p_{3},q_{3})=(29,12),\ldots .
\end{equation*}

Comment: Could you answer this for me http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2207116/424606

Comment: What does this mean, do we now use pells equation?

Comment: @SenJee It just means that a finite regular continued fraction (a continued fraction which terminates after a finite number of terms and whose partial numerators are equal to $1 $) such as the one in your question can be computed recursively using the c.f. fundamental recurrence. If a c.f. does not terminate it can be computed using the same recurrence as well, provided that it converges.

Comment: For $[a;b,c,d,x]$ we can say it is equal to $x[a;b,c,d]+[a;b,c]$. If $[a;b,c,d]$ is equal to $P_{n+1}/Pn$ , then what is $[a;b,c,d,x]$ ?

Comment: @SenJee We can say that if $[a_0; a_1, \,\dots, a_n]=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$, then $[a_0; a_1, \,\dots, a_{n-1}, x]=\frac{x p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}}{x p_{n-1}+p_{n-2}}.$ See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems).